# PHP getting Google Calendar API events list not working offline

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I tried using the Google API PHP Client (https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) and following their tutorials and examples, but also other ones.

This is my code.

index.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('xxx.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly');

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    
// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
  $calendarId = 'primary';
  $optParams = array(
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'orderBy' => 'startTime',
    'singleEvents' => TRUE,
    'timeMin' => date('c'),
  );
  
  $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
  $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

  if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
    print "No upcoming events found.<br />";
  } else {
    print "Upcoming events:<br />";
    foreach ($results->getItems() as $event) {
      $start = $event->start->dateTime;
      if (empty($start)) {
        $start = $event->start->date;
      }
      printf("%s (%s)<br />", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
  }
  
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/xxx/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

oauth2callback.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google\Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('xxx.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/xxx/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly');

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/xxx/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I have two problems:

1. When Google asks for my account's OAuth it says my app is not safe. How could I fix that?
2. If I change web browser, Google asks for my OAuth again (which others are not supposed to know), but I wanted an authomatic authorization that doesn't require OAuth every time and that means even when my account is 'offline'.

My goal is letting people who are using my web app (so not everyone) read (only) my calendar list of next N events.

Comment: `it says my app is not safe`..we'd have to see the exact error/warning message you're receiving, in order to make precise suggestions. Also, have you googled the message to see if any help exists already about it?

Comment: `I wanted an authomatic authorization that doesn't require OAuth every time and that means even when my account is 'offline'`...then you need to use a service account instead of a user-initiated authentication flow, so it doesn't ever prompt for user credentials. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account . You can set this up within your google account settings so that the app can use your account's calendar data.

Comment: See also https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Service Account instead of a user-initiated authentication flow, so it doesn't ever prompt for user credentials.

See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account for setup details. You can configure this within your google account settings so that the PHP app can use your Google account's calendar data when it authenticates using the service account credentials. These credentials cannot be used to access any other Google accounts (unlike with the front-end flow where the user can enter different account credentials and therefore access their own account data through your app instead).

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts has examples of usage of a Service Account with the Google API PHP client library.